# Two-side blending of faces with opacity

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have drawn two polygons with 50% transparency, but it works only in one side (look images).

Goood blending:
[image]

But from another point of view:
[image]

Blue tubes are the axis with 0% transparency.

Here's the code of initialization:

```
qglClearColor(QColor::fromCmykF(0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0));

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

And drawing:

```
static const GLfloat P1[3] = { 0.0, -1.0, +2.0 };
static const GLfloat P2[3] = { +1.73205081, -1.0, -1.0 };
static const GLfloat P3[3] = { -1.73205081, -1.0, -1.0 };
static const GLfloat P4[3] = { 0.0, +2.0, 0.0 };

static const GLfloat * const coords[4][3] = {
        { P1, P2, P3 }, { P1, P3, P4 }, { P1, P4, P2 }, { P2, P4, P3 }
};

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.0);

glScalef(scaling, scaling, scaling);

glRotatef(rotationX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(rotationY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(rotationZ, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    glLoadName(i);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    QColor color = faceColors[i];
    color.setAlpha(50);
    qglColor(color);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        glVertex3f(coords[i][j][0], coords[i][j][1],
            coords[i][j][2]);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

My point is to draw and explore scene like this one
[image]
<sub>(source: [wblut.com](http://www.wblut.com/blog/wp-content/2009/04/voronoi3db2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I have found out that if I draw polygons in another sequence the problem inverts.

Comment: That suggests to me it could be something to do with backface culling. Try calling this at the start: `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`

Comment: @Brett culling is disabled. It is not the reason unfortunetaly. I think this problem is caused by some blending features that I don't know.

Comment: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` This is probably causing your problem. Blending and depth-testing do not go well with each other

Comment: @user1781290 without GL_DETH_TEST axes, which have no transparency look like bad. http://i.imgur.com/DH4lGWN.png
I suppose that I need to work with depth buffer somehow.

Comment: You need to render in two passes. First render all solid geometry with depth-testing and in the second pass, leave on the depth-testing, but disable depthbuffer-writes and render with blending

Comment: @user1781290 you are right. I had read it in the docs just when u wrote the comment.

Write the answer and i will put the tick on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in rendering with both blending and depth-testing. When a part of the geometry is found to be behind another part of geometry in the scene by the depth-test, it is discarded instead of blended.

To solve this, render in two steps

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
// Render solid geometry here

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
// Render transparent geometry here
```

In the first step solid geometry is drawn as usual without blending. Transparent geometry is drawn in the second pass without changing the depth buffer. Depth-testing is still enabled to avoid blending over solid geometry in front of the transparent parts.

Comment: This works only in very simple cases, where you have only one layer of transparent geometry. Otherwise, you have to sort the transparent geometry back to front, and draw it in that order. And if you have overlapping transparent objects, you will have to split them so that you can draw them in back to front order.

Comment: @RetoKoradi This answer is not a general purpose approach on blending, but just a simple two-pass render example. It seems to be enough for the OPs needs